# Un-inherit from std::basic_string

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, stdstring

Basically, I have a large project that uses a custom utility class `c_string` that inherits from `std::basic_string<char>`. For numerous reasons, I would like to edit this class so that

1. It does not derive from `std::basic_string<char>`
2. I do not have to re-implement all the functions
3. I do not have to touch every file that uses `c_string`

So I want to change from:

```
class c_string : public std::basic_string<char>
{
public:
    typedef std::basic_string<char> Base;

    c_string() : Base() {}
}
```

To:

```
class c_string
{

...

public:

    ...

    c_string() {...}
}
```

So, I'm wondering if anyone has a good strategy for making this change with minimal impact.

Comment: So why do you want to not derive from basic_string?  Is it that the header is messing you up?

Comment: @NathanMonteleone: Standard library types aren't meant for inheritance, not public inheritance at least...

Comment: @NathanMonteleone The glaring issue for my situation is moving from v90 (works) to the v100 compiler causes npos to be an unresolved external symbol when linking

Comment: @zdp You might be able to work around that.  Is it complaining about basic_string<char>::npos or c_string::npos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class adds custom functionality (that your project needs) over `std::string`, then you're out of luck: you will either have to encapsulate `std::string` (and implement all methods to forward to `std::string` implementation) or inherit from `std::string` (inheriting from `std::string` is not a good idea in general).

If your class doesn't add extra functionality over `std::string`, then replace `class c_string { ... }` with `typedef std::string c_string;`.

Comment: Or an alias template in case you use C++11.

Answer (score 1):

There is another thing you can do and that is to change the public inheritance with private inheritance. Doing that, you will get a bunch of compile errors, because all of string's memberfunctions are now private to the clients of your class. You can then selectively make these public:

```
class my_string: std::string {
public:
    typedef std::string base; // convenience
    using base::const_iterator;
    using base::begin;
    using base::end;
};
```

You should understand private derivation not as "my_string is a std::string" but "my_string is implemented in terms of std::string". This technique avoids some of the downsides (implicit conversion, slicing etc) of deriving from a type that is not intended to be a baseclass, like std::string. Doing this conversion is easy, it's just work with little risk of breaking anything. Afterwards though, you have control over the forwarded interfaces, which makes conversion and refactoring much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any way that you could avoid at least wrapping all the functions.  The most straightforward way would be to have a private basic_string member, and just write wrappers that call the same function on that member.

Answer (score 0):

I have nearly the same problem as zdp. Not inherit from std::string leads in a lot of code not to use methods (we have a lot like this) as void Foo(string &s_) where a string is the parameter in the function and the user puts a my_string to Foo(). In short therm: Inherit from std::string and you can send your my_string to any function which takes a my_string OR a std::string as parameter. 
I would like to rewrite my my_string class but there are a lot of code with this problem in other hands and a lot of people have to change their code too. 
One bad choice 14 years ago....... sh..